# Complex integral 1: $\int_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{\cos^2t}{13+12\cos t}dt$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, definite-integrals

$$\int_{0}^{2\pi} \dfrac{\cos^2t}{13+12\cos t}dt$$
$$\int_{0}^{2\pi} \dfrac{\cos2t+1}{13+12\cos t}dt$$
$$\int_{0}^{2\pi} \dfrac{\cos2t}{13+12\cos t}dt+\int_{0}^{2\pi} \dfrac{1}{13+12\cos t}dt$$

Of course, $\int_{0}^{2\pi} \dfrac{1}{13+12\cos t}dt$ is rather easy I suppose to evaluate. You can take $\tan t/2 = y$ and so on.

let $I = \int_{0}^{2\pi} \dfrac{\cos2t}{13+12\cos t}dt$ and $J = \int_{0}^{2\pi} \dfrac{\sin2t}{13+12\cos t}dt$

For the other one, one ideea is to take $I+iJ = \dfrac{e^{i2t}}{13+12\cos t}dt$

But what about $I-iJ$? Is this approach good? I got stuck here...

Comment: You forgot a factor of $\dfrac{1}{2}$ going from step 1 to step 2.

Comment: Did you want to solve this using contour integration?  Or did you want to use real analysis only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $\cos(t) = \frac{e^{it}+e^{-it}}{2}$, hence by setting $e^{it}=z$ we have

$$ \int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{\cos^2(t)}{13+12\cos t}\,dt = \oint_{|z|=1}\frac{-i(1+z^2)^2}{4z^2(3+2z)(2+3z)}\,dz$$
and by setting $f(z)=\frac{(1+z^2)^2}{4z^2(3+2z)(2+3z)}$ we have that $f(z)$ is a meromorphic function and its poles inside the unit disk lie at $0$ and $-\frac{2}{3}$. The residue at $0$ equals $-\frac{13}{144}$ and the residue at $-\frac{2}{3}$ equals $\frac{169}{720}$, hence the original integral equals
$$ 2\pi\left(-\frac{13}{144}+\frac{169}{720}\right)=\color{red}{\frac{13}{45}\,\pi}.$$

---

There is an efficient real counterpart. By symmetry the original integral equals
$$ 26\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{\cos^2(t)}{13^2-12^2\cos^2 t}\,dt = 52\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{\cos^2(t)}{13^2-12^2\cos^2 t}\,dt$$
or, by substituting $t=\arctan u$,
$$ 52\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{du}{(1+u^2)(25+169u^2)} $$
that is straightforward to compute by partial fraction decomposition.

Answer (score 3):

HINT:

Use [Partial Fraction Decomposition](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PartialFractionDecomposition.html) to write $$\dfrac{\cos^2t}{13+12\cos t}=A\cos t+B+\dfrac C{13+12\cos t}$$

Use *[Weierstrass Substitution](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/WeierstrassSubstitution.html)* for the last part